# curl error when calling rsconnect::setAccount

Tags: r, curl, shiny, shinyapps

I just got a new computer and for some reason this is happening to me when I try to run the rsconnect command in my window. Has anyone else have the same problem. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is almost certainly caused by compiling curl/libcurl with `./configure --without-ssl`

re-compile curl and make sure to run ./configure with `--with-ssl`, and this error should go away.

(read more on how to compile curl/libcurl here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html )